# why does add_rewrite_rule refresh and loose url variables

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am using:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );  
function add_author_rules() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        "support/([^/]+)/?", "index.php?category=$matches[1]", "top");   
}
```

in the `themes/function.php`

when I enter the address:

```
http://localhost/support/funding
```

the url changes to:

```
http://localhost
```

and the variable is not set:

```
print_r($_GET);
$category = get_query_var('category');
echo '!'.$category.'!';
```

both give an empty result

the `.htaccess` is unchanged and is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In case I wasnt clear I want:

`/support/funding` to remain in the address bar and me to have access to the variable category which would be 'funding' in this case

Answer (score 4):

First of all, always develop with [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) so you can see errors. This will reveal the first issue: `Undefined variable: matches`. Your rule should be in single quotes so it's passed as a string and the `$matches` variable is not expanded.

The second issue is that there is no `category` query var, if you're trying to set a default WordPress category, it should be `category_name`.

This is tested and working in TwentyTwelve theme:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );  
function add_author_rules() {   
    add_rewrite_rule(  
        'support/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]', 'top'
    );   
}
```

Note that you will not see any change to .htaccess as this is an *internal* rewrite.

If `category` is your own custom query var, you need to register query vars with WordPress so it is aware of them, though I would not suggest using just `category`.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa_query_vars' );
function wpa_query_vars($query_vars){
    $query_vars[] = 'wpa_category';
    return $query_vars;
}
```